# replace a part of file with another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i have two files. 
the 1st file looks something like this:

```
'1'     'PS'    'at5g38660'     'Symbols: APE1 | APE1'  T
'1.1'   'PS.lightreaction'      ''      ''
'1.1.1' 'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II'       ''      ''
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        'at1g15820'     'Symbols: LHCB6, '    T
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        'at1g29910'     'Symbols: CAB3'        T
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        'at1g29920'     'Symbols: CAB2'        T
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        'at1g29930'     'Symbols: CAB1'        T
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        'at1g76570'     'chlorophyll A-B'       T
'1.1.1.2'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.PSII'            'at1g03600'     'photosystem II'        T
'1.1.1.2'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.PSII'      'at1g05385'    'photosystem II 11 kDa'  T
'1.1.1.2'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.PSII'     'at1g06680'     'Symbols: PSBP-1SII-P'     T
```

2nd file:

```
at5g38660       2356766_1

at1g15820       3043768_9

at1g29930       2325825_1

at1g76570       2921847_3

at1g03600       2368346_5

at1g05385       2321872_2
```

expected output:

```
'1'     'PS'    '2356766_1'     'Symbols: APE1 | APE1'  T
'1.1'   'PS.lightreaction'      ''      ''
'1.1.1' 'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II'       ''      ''
'1.1.1.1 'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        '3043768_9'     'Symbols: LHCB6, '    T
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        ''     ''       
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        ''     ''        
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        '2325825_1'     'Symbols: CAB1'        T
'1.1.1.1'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.LHC-II'        '2921847_3'     'chlorophyll A-B'       T
'1.1.1.2'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.PSII'            '2368346_5'     'photosystem II'        T
'1.1.1.2'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.PSII'      '2321872_2'    'photosystem II 11 kDa'  T
'1.1.1.2'       'PS.lightreaction.photosystem II.PSII'     ''     ''
```

here i wish to replace the 'at5g38660' of 1st file with 2356766_1.. and so on.

if there is a match then all the columns in 1st file remains same except the third(which gets replaced by a value from 2nd file).

if there is no match then i wish to print the first and second column of 1st file and third and fourth and fifth column as blanl. (shown in expected output)

coding tired:

```
import sys
ara_red_file  = open (sys.argv[1]).readlines()
ara_map_file     = open (sys.argv[2]).readlines()
for line in ara_red__file:
    split_line = line.split('\t')
    ara_id1    = split_line[0]
    redbean_id = split_line[1]
    for lines in ara_map_file:
        split_line  = lines.split('\t')
        bincode     = split_line[0]
        name        = split_line[1]
        ara_id2     = split_line[2]
        description = split_line[3]
        code_type   = split_line[4]
            if ara_id2 == ara_id1: 
                print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+"'"+redbean_id+"'"+'\t'+description +'\t'+code_type
            elif ara_id2 != ara_id1: 
                print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+ "''" +'\t'+ "''"
```

here the problem i face is i dont get the expected output.. it dosen't check the lat if condition and prints the last elif condition print.

Comment: are you trying to replace ids like "at5g38660" with  "2356766_1"?

Comment: ya i am trying to replace them and print the lines.. if there is no match then also i have to print the line except that i dont have to print 3rd, 4th, and 5th column of the first file..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first to create a dictionary with the second file, and make sure you store it fine, and then make the for loop you're using but you have to make sure you're doing well the comparisons.

to create the dictionary from the file:

```
dict = {}
ara_red_file  = open (sys.argv[1]).readlines()
for line in ara_red__file:
    split_line = line.split('\t')
    dict[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]
```

So we supose the dictionary ends "like" this:

```
#####ADDED COMMAS AT THE END OF EACH ELEMENT
dict = {
'at5g38660': 12345,
'at5g386x2': 45678,
'at5g386x3': 123,
'at5g386x4': 5555,
}
```

so now you have to check if there is a key in dict, like the 3rd column on your first file like this:

```
ara_map_file     = open (sys.argv[2]).readlines())
for lines in ara_map_file:
        split_line  = lines.split('\t')
        bincode     = split_line[0]
        name        = split_line[1]
        ara_id2     = split_line[2]
        description = split_line[3]
        code_type   = split_line[4]
            if dict.get(ara_id2): #CHANGED HERE @@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
                print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+"'"+dict[ara_id2]+"'"+'\t'+description +'\t'+code_type
            else: 
                print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+ "''" +'\t'+ "''"
```

Comment: i get this key error:

        if dict[ara_id2]:

KeyError: "'at5g38660'"

Comment: You make the dict with the for loop or just copy my "example" dict ? Because the dict example is just to clarify how the dict store the info but  I didn't check the syntax. I didn't write the commas after each element. it should be like dict = {
'at5g38660': 12345,
'at5g386x2': 45678,
'at5g386x3': 123,
'at5g386x4': 5555,
}

Comment: no i tried with my own. i used the way you asked me to check.. but i am getting the key error..

Comment: Before the changes it was: if dict[ara_id2].... but if the key doesn't exists return error, but if you make dict.get(ara_id2) return true if exists and false if doesn't exists

Comment: print the dictionary on the screen and check if is well stored the information. If you call dict in your code, it should show the stored info, because if never enter the if is because never find ara_id2, so it could be the dict is not well generated, or because you have to convert the string you passing to dict.get

Comment: If the string in ara_id2 match any dict key, it should enter the if condition... I tried that on my pc. I recommend you to print ara_id2, and the keys of dict at the same time, and check if the keys are stored in the same way as you passed

Comment: ya it should but it is not entering.. i dont know wht is the error now.. acc to me the logic is correct but i cant find my own error... :(

Comment: post here the dict with the values, and some ara_id2 that should enter in the if, but exactly the same as the console shows to you

Comment: here is the dict which is generated.. it is a small part i m sending you..

{'at2g28940': '2278820_3', 'at1g15290': '3045223_8', 'at2g41900': '3002022_4', 'at4g32410': '2914721_4', 'at4g28860': '3031068_2', 'at1g21690': '2311021_5', 'at4g12040': '2371795_6', 'at1g16080': '2985898_6', 'at5g03280': '3041566_3', 'at5g13150': '3015488_4', 'at5g16300': '3032147_1', 'at3g22960': '3037756_2', 'at5g26570': '3045340_7', 'at5g03430': '3001939_5', 'at4g16970': '2371682_8', 'at2g38550': '2383220_1', 'at1g49390': '3020933_1'}

Comment: That's perfect... and now print the ara_id2 values, the dictionary should work perfectly. Could you try to change if dict.get(ara_id2): for if dict.get('at2g28940'): and see if enter on that if ?. It seems that the problem could be ara_id2, but I don't understand why, and that things are just format stuff, can help you so much from distance... :S

Comment: here are the printed ara_id2 

'at5g38660'
''
''
'at1g15820'
'at1g29910'
'at1g29920'
'at1g29930'
'at1g76570'
'at2g05070'
'at2g05100'

Comment: its not working even if i change to -->    if dict.get('at2g28940'):

--- i get key error with this... :(

Comment: Are you getting key error in wich line ? in the if dict.get(ara_id2): line ? are you passing the 'at2g28940' with '  ' ?

Comment: I'm trying to get a key error in my console using dict.get() and I never get a key error, or find the key and returned it, or don't find the value and return nothing. Do you have the 2 last lines well ? changed "dict[ara_id2]" for "dict.get(ara_id2)" ???

Comment: ya i have chaged them.. i m am getting this key error msg:     print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+"'"+dict[ara_id2]+"'"+'\t'+description +'\t'+code_type
KeyError: "'at5g38660'"

Comment: change the print from dict[ara_id2] to dict.get(ara_id2). But It should work, because if it enter the if is because the key exists. I strongly recommend to check the python dictionaries syntax because it's awesome the facilities you get managing dictionaries well

Comment: this is my if loop cond..

        if dict.get(ara_id2):
                print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+"'"+dict[ara_id2]+"'"+'\t'+description +'\t'+code_type
        else:
                print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+ "''" +'\t'+ "''"

Comment: change your code to:  if dict.get(ara_id2): print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+"'"+dict.get(ara_id2)+"'"+'\t'+description +'\t'+code_type else: print bincode+'\t'+name+'\t'+ "''" +'\t'+ "''"

Comment: again if loop is not executing.. :( only else loop gets printed.. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40726/discussion-between-rhkss-and-liarez)